# Conditional Suggestions using Lucene SpellChecker

Tags: hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

Scenario:
I have many projects. Each project has many modules & each module has its description.

Now i'm providing search for module description. For suggestion of misspelled words, i'm using SpellChecker API. I have created simple dictionary using LuceneDictionary. The problem is since the index doesn't have any reference to project ids, suggestions comes from all modules, where as i want to search within some project only. How can i properly create index for such case?

Some more info: I'm using Hibernate Search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Index Sharding**

This looks like a good fit for the Sharding feature of Hibernate Search: [10.5. Sharding indexes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#advanced-features-sharding).

Essentially you can have each project have its dedicated index.

By default queries will run on an "aggregation view" of all indexes but you can open a specific index if you're using the lower level [IndexReader API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#IndexReaders) (just open the IndexReader by full name - including the shard id) or apply a filter on your queries: see [enter link description here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-filter-shard).

**Multi-Tenancy**

Alternatively if your "projects" represent different data sets which need to be totally isolated from each other, you can have a look at [Hibernate ORM's native support for multi-tenancy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-multi-tenancy).

[Hibernate Search works fine with ORM's multi-tenancy feature](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-multi-tenancy) as well, however in such cases people will want to combine multi-tenancy with sharding, as otherwise if you open a native IndexReader you'll still access all data from all tenants.